# populate Mongoose subdocument

Tags: mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have an issue regarding a mongoose schema :

```
`var ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    resources: [{
        employee: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee'},
        dailyRate: Number
    }],`...
```

and I'm trying with no success to populate the `resources.employee` field... already tried :

- `.populate('resources.employee')`
- `.populate('resources.employee',  model: 'Employee'})`
- etc ...

any advice ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, was just my insert that did not work...

the correct syntax is :

`.populate({path:'resources.employee', model:'Employee'})`